# docker-composr.yml command argument

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose, containers

Is there a way to make this command run in a container, as an argument of the docker-compose.yml?

command:

```
"rabbitmqctl set_policy ha "example-queue" '{"ha-mode":"all", "ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}' --priority 1 --apply-to queues"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.3'
services:
rabbit1:
    image: rabbitmq:v378
    hostname: rabbit1
    environment:
        - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=abcdefg
    volumes:
        - ./enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
        - ./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
        - ./definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
    ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672"
        - "25672:25672"
        - "4369:4369"
```

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by **as any argument of the docker compose**? or do you want the command to be executed every time you run the image in a docker container?

Comment: Argument as ports, volumes, etc. Is it possible to add a command like those others?

Comment: use the `ENTRYPOINT` label of `docker-compose` and you will be able to run any command from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose has support for command as a parameter:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command

Comment: Tried this: command: - "rabbitmqctl set_policy ha "example-queue" '{"ha-mode":"all", "ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}' --priority 1 --apply-to queues" - ain't no worked :(

Comment: Did you leave that `-` after the `:`?. Also there's a lot of quote marks in there

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to run the command:

`rabbitmqctl set_policy ha "example-queue" '{"ha-mode":"all", "ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}' --priority 1 --apply-to queues`

whenever you run the container. Then simply add the following in your docker-compose

```
entrypoint:
     - rabbitmqctl 
     - set_policy 
     - ha 
     - "example-queue" 
     - '{"ha-mode":"all", "ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}' 
     - --priority 
     - 1 
     - --apply-to 
     - queues
```

I am pretty sure this should work but if doesn't, do a comment, we will discuss and find out the errors.

Also, your command is little unclear to me, so I don't know which option relates to which values. It is possible that `--priority=1` should be written instead writing them in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using a definitions file, so why are you not completing it with the policy information?

```
"policies": [
  {
    "vhost": "/",
    "name": "ha",
    "pattern": "example-queue",
    "apply-to": "queues",
    "definition": {
      "ha-mode": "all",
      "ha-sync-mode": "automatic"
    },
    "priority": 1
  }
]
```

That's the easiest way, and it doesn't involve Docker at all.